# Does an impure function return anything?

Tags: java, methods, return

An impure function does not return anything. That is what my computer textbook says. I am not sure it is correct as by definition an impure function is a function which changes the state of the parameters passed to it. The parameter is generally an object.

e.g.:

```
void impurefunc(Class object)
{
   object.var = 9; //object's variable changed
}
```

If it returns anything does it remain impure?

Comment: that's the definition for pure function

Comment: java doesn't have functions, it has methods. All methods must return something, unless declared to return `void`, in which case nothing is returned. Your code won't compile without adding `void` before the method name.

Comment: (Fixed) A pure function is a function that doesn't cause any (observable) side effects.  Modifying the arguments is only one kind of side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An impure function does not return anything. That is what a computer textbook says.

It’s wrong. An impure function can indeed return anything after doing whatever impure things it does. This is true in Java and every other language I know of.

Comment: are u sure ? cuz i have my computer exams today

Comment: @Shubham: Very. (If you look at Haskell, too, what else is an `IO a` doing?)